# How to Attach Google Drive File with sendMail Function in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to attach a file (pdfName) from Google Drive to sendMail function in Apps Script.  Currently not pulling with the code I have below.  Everything else works perfectly.  Just having trouble with the attach portion.

```
function send(formObj) {
  var to = formObj.email;
  var body = formObj.body;
  var sheetName = "POTemplate";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var poNo = sourceSheet.getRange("b2").getValue();
  var pdfName = "Sample PO Hi Eric " + poNo;
  var subject = poNo + " Good morning, Eric";
  var attach = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName);
   MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {attachments:[attach]});
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, according to the [GAS Documentation on sendMail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)), the `attachments` argument requires a `BlobSource[]` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source)). However getFilesByName() returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)). You need to give MailApp any filetype that implements [BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source).

So to clarify the main issue is that you are trying to give sendMail a list of files (in the form of FileIterator) instead of just one file.

So something like this should work:

```
function send(formObj) {
  var to = formObj.email;
  var body = formObj.body;
  var sheetName = "POTemplate";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var poNo = sourceSheet.getRange("b2").getValue();
  var pdfName = "Sample PO Hi Eric " + poNo;
  var subject = poNo + " Good morning, Eric";


  var listOfFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName); //returns FileIterator of files that match name given.
  if(listOfFiles.hasNext()){ //We should check if there is a file in there and die if not.
    var file = listOfFiles.next(); //gets first file in list.
    MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {attachments:[file]});
  }else{
    console.log("Error no file in listOfFiles. Email not sent.");
  }
 }
```

**edit:** I just did some testing and it looks like, for PDFs, the getBlob() is not necessary so I have removed it from my code!

Comment: I believe it should be `listofFiles.next().getBlob()`

Comment: Thanks Jack, I wasn't sure as I havn't used it with PDFs before! I've update my answer.

Comment: Well, I take that back. Seems like `Google Files` are a valid blob source

Comment: Haha, yes, I just checked as well.