# Attach a Google Docs file in an email with Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to attach a Google Docs file to an email using Google App Scripts.
I have a folder with the file inside and the idea is to get the file from there and send it by email using also an email address that is saved in a google sheet.

I founded and used this:

```
function emailDocTestasDocx() {
  var id = '1egjazIip6zuPneKh2sVFTvbK06asd4ZgAvrgjw';// an example of Google doc
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1egjaasdasdeKh2sVFTvbK06z4JbPqnm4ZgAvrgjw';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  MailApp.sendEmail(me, 'test', 'see attachment', {attachments:[doc]});
}
```

It works but the final attachment is an html that redirects me to the doc inside the folder. I don't want that. I want to send the attachment but I didn't found a way to to this yet.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Google Docs are not something you can open outside of cloud so you cannot attach them with the mail. You can either attach pdf or the docx using export.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Attach Google Drive File with sendMail Function in Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831263/how-to-attach-google-drive-file-with-sendmail-function-in-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

As what **@Karan** have mentioned on the comments, **Google Docs** are not something you can open outside of the cloud (it is always being opened via docs.google.com website via a link) so you cannot attach them as a file on the mail. You can either attach the document as **PDF** or export the Docs file first as a document with **.docx** extension & then save the file on your Google Drive:

***Sample tweaked script that will send attach the Google doc file as PDF:***

```
function emailDocTestasDocx() {
  var id = '1egjazIip6zuPneKh2sVFTvbK06asd4ZgAvrgjw';// an example of Google doc
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1egjaasdasdeKh2sVFTvbK06z4JbPqnm4ZgAvrgjw';
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(id); //used ID to get the file saved in your Drive using DriveApp.getFileById() method
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  MailApp.sendEmail(me, 'test', 'see attachment', {attachments:[doc]}); //attach the file via email
}
```

***Sample Result***

> [image]

You may also check the answers from these similar posts:

- [Convert Google Doc to PDF using Google Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38912944/15384825)
- [Google Apps Script: Send docx email attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378322/15384825)
- [Send email with an attachment located in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79324/send-email-with-an-attachment-located-in-google-drive)